# Unit test for Event Emitter Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, sinon, eventemitter

I created a simple class for polling by `Event Emitter` of Nodejs
For example:

```js
import EventEmitter from "events";
import config from "../config";

export class Poller extends EventEmitter {
  constructor(private timeout: number = config.pollingTime) {
    super();
    this.timeout = timeout;
  }

  poll() {
    setTimeout(() => this.emit("poll"), this.timeout);
  }

  onPoll(fn: any) {
    this.on("poll", fn); // listen action "poll", and run function "fn"
  }
}
```

But I don't know to write the right test for `Class`. This my unit test

```js
import Sinon from "sinon";
import { Poller } from "./polling";
import { expect } from "chai";

describe("Polling", () => {
  it("should emit the function", async () => {
    let spy = Sinon.spy();
    let poller = new Poller();

    poller.onPoll(spy);
    poller.poll();

    expect(spy.called).to.be.true;
  });
});
```

But It always false

```
  1) Polling
       should emit the function:

      AssertionError: expected false to be true
      + expected - actual

      -false
      +true
```

Please tell me what's wrong with my test file. Thank you very much !

Comment: Use `sinon.useFakeTimers()` as described in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/17446401/5979775

Comment: Thanks for your response. It works. Can you post your answer so I can accept for you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow [sinon doc](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v4.4.2/fake-timers/)

Quick fix

```
import Sinon from "sinon";
import { Poller } from "./polling";
import { expect } from "chai";
import config from "../config";

describe("Polling", () => {
  it("should emit the function", async () => {
    // create a clock to control setTimeout function
    const clock = Sinon.useFakeTimers();
    let spy = Sinon.spy();
    let poller = new Poller();

    poller.onPoll(spy);
    poller.poll(); // the setTimeout function has been locked

    // "unlock" the setTimeout function with a "tick"
    clock.tick(config.pollingTime + 10); // add 10ms to pass setTimeout in "poll()"

    expect(spy.called).to.be.true;
  });
});
```